# Local file open IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I need to create a local website. Everything needs to work from desktop, no PHP.

My problem is that I am trying to link to a pdf and on IE the link is not working. I need some help with a workaround or an idea.

```
<div><a href="Module1.pdf" target="_blank">&nbsp;</a></div>
```

Comment: that depends on your browser settings. Some browsers open the .pdf in the browser others will offer you to download the .pdf !

Comment: When you say "the link is not working" - what happens?

Comment: Does it work in other browsers?

Comment: Yes other browsers works perfect

Comment: Did you find any solution or references to this? I saw the same problem... setting target="_blank" for a PDF link opens a blank tab in IE without the PDF.

Comment: Hey soory no i coudn't find any solution, i had to make a different html wich contained images cutted from the pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is : You have a link but you can't see it cause your text is a non breaking space... but why?

```
<div><a href="Module1.pdf" target="_blank">Your Text Here</a></div>
```

WARNING: target="_blank" is not done!

http://jalada.co.uk/2011/02/10/why-you-shouldnt-use-target_blank-and-what-to-use-instead.html

Comment: Hy tnks for your sugestion but still same thing.

Comment: try to give it the style="display:block;"

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a space for the link ? Try writing anything instead.

```
<div><a href="Module1.pdf" target="_blank">download</a></div>
```

Comment: If only would be that simple.

Comment: @BloodRayneBlood why is it not that simple?

Comment: I already tryed like everthing i could posible imagine this was 1 of those ideeas and still not working :(

Comment: @BloodRayneBlood What happens when you try it ?

Comment: @BloodRayneBlood Please edit your question and explain what "not working" means.

Comment: Not working means Nothing is happening,but on the other browsers works perfectly

Comment: @BloodRayneBlood: works fine for me, also with IE (IE8 8.0.6001.18702). Maybe there's a problem in the surrounding page. Post the full page (minimal example) where the link doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Try it with any other page linking PDFs using IE. Maybe your PDF plugin is missing or acting weird.

After all the other answers not working, this is my last resort, because that's completely valid HTML.